# Destructuring a function/method breaks things in Firestore - How?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, es6-class, destructuring

Was just playing with Firestore and got everything working. I had this snippet:

```
this.db.collection('settings').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    this.cachedSettings[doc.id] = doc.data();
  });
});
```

But as soon as I destructing data, everything broke. Was a bit confused of what was happening. I assumed it had something to do with `this` binding.

```
this.db.collection('settings').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(({ id, data }) => {
    this.cachedSettings[id] = data();
  });
});
```

If anyone has any reference, that's ok as well. I couldn't find one since I don't know the proper wording for this problem. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found the culprit. It's due to the nature of `this` in JavaScript. Consider this example:

```
class Hello {
  constructor() {
    this.hello = "Hello";
  }

  returnString() {
    return this.hello;
  }
}

const { returnString } = new Hello();

console.log(returnString());
```

This would log `undefined`. Why? - because `this` here refers to the function `returnString` itself when destructured, hence `undefined`.

However, this would work:

```
console.log(new Hello().returnString())
```

In order for the first snippet to work, we need to bind `returnString` to the class, like so:

```
class Hello {
  constructor() {
    this.hello = "Hello";
    this.returnString = this.returnString.bind(this);
  }

  returnString() {
    return this.hello;
  }
}

const { returnString } = new Hello();

console.log(returnString());
```

Hope it helps future readers :)